# How Do i create a link from a Java servlet in Netbeans back to a index.html or another page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, netbeans

All I am trying to do is link from the JSP back to the HTML page. I cannot find a simple example anywhere online. Also where would i put it, in the `doGet`, `doPost`, or somewhere else? I would prefer to be able to make it a button, but at this point i will take any link that works.

```
 import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(urlPatterns =
{
"/a"
})
public class a extends HttpServlet
{


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
    {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet a</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet a at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo()
{
    return "Short description";
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your codes ?

Comment: I am looking for a general answer. Link from Jsp to "page". in HTML you would do <a href="url">link text</a> in the servlet you would do.... "answer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in HTML you would do `<a href="url">link text</a>` in the servlet you
>   would do

Try the `response`:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<a href=\"index.html\">Back</a>");
out.close();
```

The above code will generate link to index.html.